# Calculating the density function $f_X$ from joint density $f_{X,Y}$

Tags: probability-distributions

X and Y have continous distribution, the joint distribution is

$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt[]{1-p^{2}}}e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-p^2)}(x^2+y^2-2pxy)}$,      ($p$ is a constante)

We need to find the marginal densiety $f_X$ of X.

I know we have to integrate over y:

$\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy=\int \frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt[]{1-p^{2}}}e^{-\frac{1}{2(1-p^2)}(x^2+y^2-2pxy)}dy$

but i can't seem to solve this can anyone help?

Comment: You should recognize this as a bivariate normal distribution with a certain mean and covariance. Then, you can read off the marginals (which are Gaussian with certain means and variances).

Comment: If we complete the square and forget about the constant in front, the problem comes down to finding
$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-((y-px)^2+(1-p^2)x^2))/(2(1-p^2))}\,dy$.
Let $y-px=u\sqrt{1-p^2}$.